# Newly installed 12.04 on Radeon or NVIDIA type of gfx card?

Tags: unity, nvidia, 12.04, radeon

I use a Nvidia Quadro NVS 290/PCIe/SSE2 at work with dual monitor setup.
Since 11.10 things has gone downwards with performance.

But now with 12.04 performance is even worse, and I can agree that the 290 is old and puny.

So when I look what low profile cards I can get to my computer today, the choice it 
Radeon HD 6570 or NVIDIA Quadro 600.

I have always used Nvidia on linux beq I think that historically their drivers worked better.
But which one do you recommend today on 12.04 and Unity3d?

--
Regards Falk

Comment: very good question... My problem is inconstancy between ubuntu and nvidia drivers. For example, ubuntue's "Displays" detects only one monitor where nvidia drivers detects 2

Answer (score 0):

Personally Nvidia , but the state of both ATI and NVidia drivers with compatibility it comes down to personal preference especially under unity , im not sure if that would change for gnome-shell